# Can I add a parameter in Sentry Javascript error?

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, sentry

Can I pass a parameter (for example, an User ID I already have on my JS) in Sentry.io?

Maybe here?:

```
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx@sentry.io/XXXXX' });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. [Docs](https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/context/?platform=browser#capturing-the-user)

```
Sentry.configureScope((scope) => {
  scope.setUser({"id": <User ID>});
});
```

Also true for any additional info

```
Sentry.configureScope((scope) => {
  scope.setExtra(<key>, <value>);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, im newbie with JS but how is it in es5? How can I do it without arrow functions?

Comment: `function(scope){...}`